# Horizontal ScrollView above a Button from LinearLayout

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

What I wish to achieve is something like this:

[image: H&M android app]

The thing is: after I tap on the circle button on the bottom layout, it appears a HorizontalScrollView with the possible colors of the product (which I will have to download).
I tried something like this:

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lay_productdetailed_bottombar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/transparent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_productdetailed_fullscreen"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Full" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_productdetailed_colors"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Colors" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_productdetailed_sizes"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Sizes" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_productdetailed_buy"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Buy" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/hscroll_productdetailed_colors"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/btn_productdetailed_colors" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lay_productdetailed_colors"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dp" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

those 2 ImageButtons are just for testing, to watch their position on the screen (Eclipse).

This code does not seem to align the horizontal scrollview above the button at all. Any ideas on how can I achieve that?

PS. Another question would be: Can I make those buttons rounded, like in the pic, without creating a a class that extends Shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add rules placing children of a `RelativeLayout` in regards of views that are not direct siblings of those views. This means that your `HorizontalScrollView` can't be placed relative to that `Button` because the `Button` isn't placed as a direct child for the  `RelativeLayout` that holds the `HorizontalScrollView`.

At best you could place the `HorizontalScrollView` above the lay_productdetailed_bottombar `LinearLayout` but, as I said, this would not give you positioning control relative to the `Button`. Another approach would be a `PopupWindow` holding the `HorizontalScrollView`.

Judging by the image you probably want the `HorizontalScrollView` to be centered around the center of the `Button` which can't be done in the xml layout, you can do it only by manually calculating the dimensions.

> Can I make those buttons rounded, like in the pic, without creating a
>   a class that extends Shape?

No, you'll need to create it yourself.